# module.exports cannot be set when passed in as argument

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

I am building my bundle using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

I have the following `service.js`:

```
(function (exports, require) {

     // ...
     var Service = function (name, region) {
         this.name = name;
         this.region = region;
         // ...
     }

     exports = Service;

})(module.exports, require);
```

Whenever I try to `require('./service')` on another module, I get an empty object as if the `exports` object was never set.

If I use `module.exports` without the argument encapsulation, everything works fine:

```
(function (require) {

   // ...
     var Service = function (name, region) {
         this.name = name;
         this.region = region;
         // ...
     }

     module.exports = Service;

})(require);
```

Why does this happen and why is this required?

Comment: Why not simply return `Service` and assign `exports` from the result of the iife?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, `example` is a variable scoped within your anonymous function, and it's pointing to `module.exports`. When you say `exports = Service`, you're changing what *`exports`* is pointing to, not what *`module.exports`* is pointing to.

When you say `module.exports = Service`, you're changing a property of `module`, which is globally scoped.

An additional illustration:

```
(function (m, require) {

    // ...
    var Service = function (name, region) {
        this.name = name;
        this.region = region;
        // ...
    }

    m.exports = Service;

})(module, require);
```

`m` points to `module`, and when we set `m.exports`, we're setting `module.exports`, since `m` and `module` point to the same object.